# How to Filter entire column containing a specific text and then remove that specific text from the filtered result in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have Column A and Column B with data.

```
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| AlexPaul.first    | 152      |
| LousieB.second   | 320      |
| ClaryA.thrid   | 777      |
| DukeGat.last   | 555      |
| HarryBot.fourth   | 458      |
| JackMalt.thrid   | 852      |
| DannyLouse.last   | 350      |
| UbarKim.thrid   | 788      |
| KyatiGott.thrid   | 796      |
| ElsiyaJaous.last   | 555      |
| GarryBewsh.fivth   | 485      |
```

I want to filter Column A containing ".last" text in it, and then on the result, I would like to remove the".last" text from the result.

This is how the result should be:

```
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| DukeGat   | 555      |
| DannyLouse   | 350      |
| ElsiyaJaous   | 555      |
```

How I do this with a single formula in Google sheets? As I have this data running 1000 of cells, I was trying ArrayFormula to combine the Filter Function and Substitute function. But I cant get it to work.

In Column D, I added

```
=FILTER(A:B,SEARCH(".last",A:A))
```

Then, in Column F, to remove ".last" from the Filtered result, I have used the below formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(D2:D,".last",""))
```

This is two-step process. Is there a better way to do this?

Can we combine this Filter function and Substitute function under a single ArrayFormula?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your formulas as

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(A:B,SEARCH(".last",A:A)),".last",""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was exactly looking for this. Now I better under how to combine two functions inside an ArrayFormula.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is by using the QUERY function wrapped in a REGEXREPLACE like

```
ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(A1:B20, "SELECT * WHERE A LIKE '%.last'"), ".last", ""))
```

Where your data is in A1:B20. Since your example has numbers, which will cause REGEXREPLACE to error, we need to overwrite the errors with an IFERROR and the same QUERY formula without the REGEXREPLACE.

```
IFERROR(
ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(A1:B20, "SELECT * WHERE A LIKE '%.last'"), ".last", "")),
QUERY(A1:B20, "SELECT * WHERE A LIKE '%.last'")
)
```